# Hosted App Out of box - No CSS?

Tags: 2013

Setup environment following this article,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/22da8c/set-up-app-environment-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1/

Please note i delete an older zone in dns which i created wrong and also renamed app domain and prefix in central admin to fix issues with apps.

but getting error,

[image]

There is no CSS

[image]